# Error: Accessing unknown getter method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Error: Accessing unknown  getter method?

Thanks...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface puppy : NSObject {
    int mack;
    int jack;
}
-(puppy *) waldo: (puppy *) f;
-(void) setMack: (int) m;
-(void) setJack: (int) j;
@end

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

#import "puppy.h"


@implementation puppy
-(void) setJack: (int) j{
    jack = j;
}

-(void) setMack: (int) m{
    mack = m;
}



-(puppy*) waldo: (puppy *) f{   

    return (f.jack + f.mack); // Error: <-- Accessing unknown "jack" getter method
                              // Error: <-- Accessing unknown "mack" getter method
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't implemented the methods `jack` and `mack`.

```
- (int) jack { return jack; }
- (int) mack { return mack; }
```

But I'd recommend just using @property and @synthesize with no ivar.

Answer (score 5):

You have not specified getter method for `jack` and `mack`. Instead of writing own getter/setter you can use property for them.

```
@interface puppy : NSObject {
    int mack;
    int jack;
}
-(puppy *) waldo: (puppy *) f;

// use property
@property (nonatomic, assign) int mack;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int jack;
@end

@implementation puppy

@synthesize jack, mack;

-(puppy*) waldo: (puppy *) f{   
    return (f.jack + f.mack);
}

@end
```

You do not need those set methods now. Both getters and setter are synthesized for you. And not asked in the question, you should return `int` from method `waldo`.

Comment: Upvoting this for pointing out the glaring pointer error in ***waldo*** method.

Comment: Note that you can drop the ivar declarations, too.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `f.jack`, it translates to `[f jack]`. You need to add a `- (int)jack` method to your interface for this to work. *Poorly worded perhaps, I also meant the method needs to be implemented. Same is the case of `mack`*

<strike>But that said, dot notation is for properties.</strike> *Isn't apt*.

It would be easier if you defined properties for `mack` and `jack` and synthesized those methods.

Comment: Dot notation *is not just for properties*.  Dot notation and properties are entirely orthogonal.   While dot notation is very much for setters and getters, the setter/getter can be traditionally declared methods.   Likewise, while @property is a means of succinctly declaring getters/setters, there is no need to use dot syntax to use them.